# laravel 8 auth::user collection from tables

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am new to laravel 8 and blade syntax.
I am working on a project where users (agents) can upload apartments.
i have agent table with corresponding model relationship

agent model

```
public function property()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Property::class, property_id, id);
    }
```

property model

```
 public function agents()
    {
    return $this->belongsTo(Agent::class, agent_id, id);

    }
```

I used breeze to build up my registration and login

i want when an agent is logged in, i will display in his dash board list of his properties.

```
@foreach(Auth::user()->properties as $property)
                                @if(($loop->count) > 0)
                                <td class="py-3 px-2">
                                    <div class="inline-flex space-x-3 items-center">
                                        <span>{{$property->propertyId}}</span>
                                    </div>
                                </td>

                                <td class="py-3 px-2">{{$property->building}}</td>
                                <td class="py-3 px-2">{{$property->rent->name}}</td>
@else
You have not uploaded any apartment
@endif
@endforeach
```

but i get error "Undefined variable $properties".

Meanwhile, {{ Auth::user()->othernames }} works fine.

AgentController

```
public function index()
    {
        return view ('dashboard', [
            'agent' => Agent::all(),
            'appointment'=>Appointment::all(),
            'properties'=>Property::all(),
            'schedule'=>AgentSchedule::all()


        ]);
    }
```

propertyController

```
public function create()
    {

        
        return view('pages.uploadapartment', [
            'states'=> State::all(),
            'areas'=>Area::all(),
            'buildings'=>building::all(),
            'buildingtypes'=>BuildingType::all(),
            'rentpaymentmethods'=>rentpaymentmethod::all(),
            'flattypes'=>flattype::all(),
        ]);

    }
```

Comment: post the code of controller

Comment: where does the `$properties` comes from ?

Comment: @xenooooo from the list of properties in property table

Comment: Can you add your controller ?

Comment: in your `index()` method it define as `$property` instead of `$properties` try changing it to `$properties`

Comment: Change your relationship, as I show in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by creating a controller for logged in agent. If the agent wants to see his property

controller

```
public function index()
     {

        
        
        return view('property.index', [
            'property'=>Property::where('agent_id', Auth::user()->id)->get() 
        ]);
     }
```

blade view

```
 @foreach($property as $property)
                        
                        
                     <div>
                        
                                {{$property->propertyId}}
                        
                        </div>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are not using user model to define the relationship!

Your relationship should be like this:

```
//In your agent model
public function properties()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Property::class, 'property_id', 'id');
}

//In property model
public function agent()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Agent::class, 'agent_id', 'id');
}
```

And when you want properties from a logged-in user, you grab them like this: `$properties = Auth::user()->properties;`

Comment: Mate, define the properties' relationship in the agent class as I told you to do.

Comment: I have done that. I want to confirm if am doing it right. In my view, i wrote foreach properties as property, if the count is more than zero, echo table data else, echo a you have no property listed. But, i have no error and this if statement is not executing coz nothing is showing in the frontend. I added this before foreach statement $properties = Auth::user()->properties;

Comment: Is the solution working or not?

Comment: my dear, it is not working. It is showing Undefined array key "properties".

Comment: Show me your current agent and property models

Comment: i updated my question according to what i have in my code. as it is in my question, so it is in my code

Comment: In your AgentController why you retun `$properties`?

Comment: if i return $property, i get error Undefined array key "properties". i dont know why it says undefined array key. even if i return property in the blade view, it is still saying same thing

Comment: You say `$property` that's why get the error, you should be calling `$properties`

Comment: please, look at my blade view to be sure that what i am doing is inline. I have in my agentcontroller properties=>property::all(), and i still get undefined array key "properties". if fill somehow my blade view is not access agentcontroller. if there is anything like that

Comment: Remove `$properties` from agentcontroller. And call it `Auth::user()->properties` in your view.

Comment: I am thinking, since this blade view renders only when an agent login, is it proper that agentcontroller should have data to be displayed on the dashboard of Auth.AuthenticatedSessionController which is the controller used by breeze to set login

Comment: Focus on what you asked for.

Comment: still gets same error. can i share my project with you through github or move this discussion to chat?

Comment: Yes, please. Do it.

Comment: You don't have enough reputation to be in a chat room.

Comment: https://github.com/oziomadot/OPAAM.git

Comment: Invite me from azafosocial@gmail.com